# CASE Statement To Repace Null Values in Cascading Fields

Tags: sql, sql-server, case

I am trying to build a CASE statement to handle the table below.

If Service1 is NULL I would like the value in Service2 to replace it. If Service1 and Service2 are NULL I would like the value in Service3 to replace it, etc ... etc ...

I would like to repeat this action on each field so they table is as compressed as possible.

I managed to build a CASE statement but I had duplicate values, as the value moved from Service2 to Service1 but also remained in Service2. I need all of the values to shift based on NULL values so the same values remain on the row but they are as compressed as possible across the columns.

[image]

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 3):

[`COALESCE`](http://modern-sql.com/feature/case#coalesce) is exactly what you are looking for:

```
SELECT COALESCE(Service1, Service2, Service3, Service4, Service5, Service6)
  FROM ...
```

`COALESCE` is a very handy short for for a `CASE` expression like this:

```
COALESCE(Service1, Service2)

CASE WHEN Service1 IS NOT NULL THEN Service1
     ELSE Service2
END
```

When you have more than two arguments, `COALESCE` is really handy.

It's also worth checking out the other `null` related `case` abbrevations:

- http://modern-sql.com/feature/case#null-related-abbrevations

Comment: Markus - Coalesce is helpful, but it still doesn't take care of the duplicate issue. See here:

![Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8yOL-7gwR6jWUlNZ2l4RzZWMjg/view?usp=sharing)